# How to cut down time talking to recruiters?

Tags: resume, job-search, recruitment

Currently, I am looking for a job and noticed that I am spending a lot of my time repeating same information to recruiters and HR personnel who call/email me. They ask me exactly the same information over and over again: describe my past experience, despite the fact that I have very detailed description of my past experience in my resume; repeatedly ask for copy of my resume & CV, despite the fact that CV & Resume are published as single .pdf file on job-search sites and on my LinkedIn page. For example, yesterday, I spend two hours with recruiters on the phone and another 30 minutes, replying to emails.
How do I cut down time this time waste ?

Comment: Either you want to look and you have to spend time replying, or you don't want to waste time replying, in which case they won't waste their time with you either. Choose. The cost of doing business comes with doing business.

Answer (score 7):

I purchased a phone number over at Numberbarn.com, and I use an e-mail anonymizer service from Blur.com.  I use this phone number, and an anonymized email address, on my resumes that I post on job sites.

The premise is real simple: one day, I'll get the job I'm looking for, and I won't want to be bothered by recruiters.  At that point, I can zap both the address and the number effortlessly.

The other thing, too - I put all the "repetitive" info on the voice mail that the Numberbarn number lets me configure.  If they're still interested after the voice mail, pressing "1" will ring through to my cell phone, or they can hang up at that point.  I still get a few stupid ones who hear the message (and what I'm looking for) and ring through anyway with requirements way out of my scope, but this still cuts out a hell of a lot of time on the phone for me.

Answer (score 3):

It happens frequently that CVs and information on LinkedIn and other such sites is outdated for many people. Even if such information is available there, they'd rather confirm that as opposed to operating using information that is 5+ years old or something.

That's why you keep having to repeat the same information over-and-over.

I've dealt with something similar in the past. What I did was, I added on my CV somewhere in the corner a line like:

> Last updated on 14th August 2016

Now, if the date is recent enough (and sufficiently visible), then it can help with this. Personally, using this technique, I've noticed a drop in the number of questions I had to answer about my past employment, university and so on.

Obviously it won't make the inconvenience completely go away. But there's a reasonable chance that it will be significantly reduced. Give it a try.